# How to properly set up OEMInformation edit commands in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm working on a program for my computing company that will allow me to run this program off of a USB drive, enter the desired information into command prompts and then have the program create and enter information for the registry keys. I'm just stuck on how the syntax / code for it would work.

I've been looking through different articles trying to find out how to do it but all of them are either too advanced for my understanding or are too vague for what my goal is.

```
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation /v System Builder /t string /d Ryan Taylor /f
```

The intended result is to create a new registry key under `HKLM\Software\Windows\CurrentVersion\OEMInformation` and have the key named `"System Builder"` then have the value pulled from a variable that was provided earlier in the program to be set as the value for the key. The key should be a string data type, not require any authentication before making edits to the registry (as it will be running multiple edits/adds I can't be bothered clicking yes haha)

As this is messing with the registry I havn't ran a test on the code yet and was wanting someone who knows what they are doing to proof check my code before I mess up my computer.

Comment: Did you read `reg /?`  and `reg add /?` carefully and try to search some related articles?

Comment: Yes, the main thing I'm stuck on is if REG_DWORD or REG_QWORD is the correct value type for a string or if its something completely different.

Answer (score -2):

Managed to sort it out after looking at more examples of code, Correct data type I was looking for is `REG_SZ` and I've worked out how the formatting works.

Comment: How is this information an answer that will help others in the future?